# Laravel Controller not adding to route list

Tags: php, laravel-5

I created a new controller with resources using the PHP artisan command:

```
php artisan make:controller AdminCategoriesController --resource
```

The file gets added to the controller folder but when I visit my route list with I see no route about it:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Here my routes list:

[image]

How can I add the categories to my routing list?

Answer (score 2):

This error is showing because you did not give instance of Resource Controller in web.php file.

```
Route::resource('route','AdminCategoriesController ');
```

When you did this , route list will show.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to add the route resource in my routes.php

```
Route::resource('/admin/categories', 'AdminCategoriesController');
```

Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using api then use this syntax to generate controller

```
php artisan make:controller API/PhotoController --api
```